# Network on Main Thread exception while trying to send e-mails in Android without user intervention

Tags: java, android, networkonmainthread

I tried to implement the sending of emails without user intervention as explained in a post that's open for this issue:
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)
but I did not send the e-mails.
I get the following error:
"NetworkOnMainThreadException"
Can anyone help?

PD. I don´t put this comment in this post because I don't leave, I guess that is closed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can  not perform network operation in main Thread.. Use asyncTask instead

Comment: StinePike thank you very much, I've solved the problem after 1 week with this error.
In fact, in the post I mentioned, I saw the response of the AsyncTask but I missed by not knowing it could be that the solution to my problem, as I have said I realized that I had read as was done with AsyncTask.

Thank you.